# installing package for react using npm

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, axios

I am beginning with react at the moment coming from pure front end development with HTML, CSS and a bit of jquery. So I got no experience with package installation. I wanted to install axios using npm.

I started with `npm install` axios and it seemed to work. But I still get the error message "axios is not defined". What I missing? Do I have to right a dependency in my package.json? And if yes how do I right it?

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "first-webapp-react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "watch": "watchify -v -d -t [ reactify --es6 ] main.js -o compiled.js",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production browserify -t [ reactify --es6 ] main.js | uglifyjs > compiled.js"
  },
  "author": "BAGGID",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.10.2",
    "react": "^0.13.2",
    "axios": "^0.15.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^9.0.8",
    "reactify": "^1.1.0",
    "uglify-js": "^2.4.20",
    "watchify": "^3.1.2"
  }
}
```

```js
var React = require('react');

var TopBar = require('./Top-bar');
var ProductPage = require('./Product-page');
var Test = require('./test');


var App = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      page: 'SearchResult',
      jobs: []
    };    
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    var _this = this;
    this.serverRequest = 
      axios.get("http://codepen.io/jobs.json")
        .then(function(result) {    
          _this.setState({
            jobs: result.data.jobs
          });
        })
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  },

 render(){
    console.log('Person: ' + this.state.person);
  return (
   <div>
    <TopBar />  
        <ProductPage />
        <Test />
   </div>
  );
 }
});

module.exports = App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>React Test</title>
 <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.4/flatly/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="assets/css/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="assets/css/baggid-standart.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="assets/css/login.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="assets/css/button-stacking.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

 <div id="main"> 
 </div>

 
 <script src="./compiled.js"></script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should add more details to your question, start by adding your package.json and the piece of code that you're using the Axios library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try to import it before use it.

```
import 'axios' from 'axios';
```

Also like this.

```
const axios = require('axios');
```

Comment: I tried it with your code and `var Axios = require('axios');` but still the same error

Comment: Change from Axios to axios, because in your code you're using like that.

Comment: That was it, thanks a lot! I didn't know that I was defining axios as the variable there. But since I tried all of the given answers I can not tell if something else was needed, too :D

Answer (score 1):

Just install via `CDN` insert this code in your html file

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Just insert this code to your html file and it will work.

so here is how your html file will be

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> <head lang="en"> 
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<title>React Test</title> 
<link href="maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.4/flatly/" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<link href="assets/css/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
</head> 
<body> <div id="main"> your content here </div> 
<script src="compiled.js"></script> 
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: I tried it but it's not working. Still the same error message.

Comment: '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>React Test</title>
 <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.4/flatly/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="assets/css/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

 <div id="main"> 
 </div>
 <script src="./compiled.js"></script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
'

Comment: I will edit the answer and post the right code on it.

Comment: you inserted the script tags without the **https://** protocol, also you used `;` on your javascript include, so it's no needed to use ; when include script

Comment: My problem was solved by adding the `var axios = require('axios');` to my app.js. I marked that as right. Thank you for your answer. I would upvote it but my vote doesn't count, yet since I am quite new to stack overflow.

Comment: Ok, remember the tips I told you about javascript , good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Check this simple example, how to use `axios`:

```js
var App = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      page: 'SearchResult',
      jobs: []
    };    
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    var _this = this;
    this.serverRequest = 
      axios.get("http://codepen.io/jobs.json")
        .then(function(result) {    
           console.log('success');
          _this.setState({
            jobs: result.data.jobs
          });
        })
        .catch(e => console.log('error', e))
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
      this.serverRequest.abort();
  },

  render: function(){
    console.log('Person: ');
    return (
     <div>
          Hello
     </div>
    );
   }
});

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to globally install axios, using

```
$ npm install -g axios
```

Comment: Did this but still the same error. Is there something else I need to know about package installation?

Comment: Can you post your package.json?  Axion should be part of dependencies block and not dev-dependencies in case you have that defined in dev-dependencies.